# What is the ruling for the person who neglects prayer on Friday?

Tags: sharia, fiqh, fatwa, jumuah

I saw a video recorded in Syria, I think it's an Islamic group. They punish a muslim person  25 jilda (الجلدة) because he didn't attend Friday prayer.

Is there any rule for that?

Comment: By "[they] *punish* a muslim person 25 jilda (الجلدة)", do you mean "they *fine* a muslim person 25 jilda (الجلدة)"?

Comment: @SalehenRahman: Yes, I mean they hit him.

Comment: extremist groups of Muslims are not standard of Islam. standard of Islam is Quran and authentic hadith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To leave of Jumu'ah without any excuse is a grave sin, the Prophet said:

> من ترك ثلاث جمعات من غير عذر كتب من المنافقين
>
> Whoever leaves three Juma'aat without any excuse he will be written
>   from the hypocrites

Narrated by Attabarani

The Prophet also was tempted to burn down the houses of those who did come to Jum'ah, but I do not know any source that supports 25 whippings.  And Allah knows best.

Comment: Could you provide references for your claims? A link or something to the hadith. And the last statement, please add references to that claim  too. If I remember right, the 3 madhabs (except hanbalits) doesn't follow that opinion.