# Is performing Salatuj Zohr instead of salatul Jumuah would be counted as qaza? is it a major sin or not?

Tags: jumuah, salat-qada

If I go to the masjid and found that slatul jumuah has just been ended, then what should I do?

- Should I perform salatuj Zohr?
- Should I perform it as qaza?
- Would it be counted as major sin?

#### Note:

I might not pick the appropriate title before, so that people claimed it as duplicate. Now, I fixed the title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missed Salat Al-Jumu'a unintentionally (while sleeping), what should I do?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7055/missed-salat-al-jumua-unintentionally-while-sleeping-what-should-i-do) and see also: "[What is the ruling for the person who neglects prayer on Friday?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10595/9123)"

Comment: You pray two rakat of Salatul Jummah alone.  It won't be qaza if the time hasn't passed.  It will be a major sin if you don't pray.